# Is the tag badge allocation broken?

Tags: support, badges

I am pretty sure that I should have been awarded a badge for [pacman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacman) by now. I have defintitely answered more than 20 times (22) and am currently sitting on 111 votes.

I understand the script is [run infrequently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253587/can-i-haz-stinkin-silver-tag-badge-plz) but, as I passed the threshold some time ago, that seems unlikely.

[image]

Do I need to make some sort of sacrifical offering to appease the elder gods? If so, please indicate the type of critter and the preferred means of dispatch.

Comment: You need to kill a `cat`. Preferably by [bludgeoning it with a  giant _s_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694/203101).

Comment: @terdon Seems the cat lives (again)...

Comment: Seems like there has to be ~14 Q's that need the pacman tag 8-)

Comment: @slm I was just going to start spamming [tag:pacman] questions...

Comment: @terdon: [Start running.](http://meta.superuser.com/a/8682/354511)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags aren't considered for tag badges until they're [used on 100 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/145982); [pacman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacman) is only at 86 questions